# Upload large database file to live server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have 1GB database that needs to be uploaded to my dev server(phpmyadmin). Is there any solution upload? Please do help me by providing the steps to upload the mysql file. i can't use SQlyog,Putty because i have just cpanel information.

Comment: You could use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to read the CSV into a temporary table, then merge it with your existing table afterwards.

Comment: i can upload one by one table. but i have a lot of table. Is there  any anthor way?@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: You could write a script to upload each file, you would only need to hard code the names of the files.  Or, if you place them in all in a single folder, you could iterate over all files in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good option with [nice interface](https://sypex.net/en/products/dumper/screenshots/) is [Sypex Dumper](https://sypex.net/en/products/dumper/downloads/). Free version is enough for your needs.

How to use:

1. Upload /sxd/ folder to your site.
2. Upload database dump into /sxd/backup/ folder. I know you can't use ssh, but surely ftp transfers must be available for your plan.
3. Open yoursite.com/sxd/ folder, login with MySQL credentials.
4. Click "Import" button in upper left corner.
5. Choose database to where you want to restore dump.
6. Charset - set necessary or leave `auto`
7. File - in this select field there will be files that are uploaded to /sxd/backup/. Choose necessary.
8. Press "Execute" button in lower right corner.
9. Wait for import process to finish. Note: sometimes progress bar may show incorrect percentage (i.e. 100% from the start).

Comment: Yeah this can slove my problem. but issue is that i can't find any select file option?

Comment: Updated answer with how-to-use explanation.

Comment: Great. I have searching from morning.  But now is make a day. Thank you so much :) @Vaviloff

Comment: Give me a small issue not importing all tables?

Comment: Do you mean it's not importing all tables? Any erorrs on screen or in server error log?

Comment: MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\' at line 2 (/sxd/index.php:1594)

Comment: I have uploaded two databases with  Sypex Dumper which was working fine but those database's was small. while i have another database which have 208 table's which create the above error @Vaviloff

Comment: Could be that the large database dump is somehow corrupted. Have you checked that it's valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117933/discussion-between-sajid-anwar-and-vaviloff).

Comment: I do't know more about. but working on localhost fine  :)

Answer (score 1):

BigDump is a great script for uploading large databases. You find it at http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/. When exporting database you should also remember to adjust "Maximal length of created query" in phpmyadmin. 300 is a good value for Bigdump.